# Installing old extension using g.extension of GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script

I am new to GRASS GIS and trying to get this extension I found working.

https://gitlab.com/invafish/r.stream.culvert

So, it fails to find if I try g.extension

```
g.extension r.stream.culvert url=” https://gitlab.com/invafish/r.stream.culvert”
```

[image]

It seemed like the r.stream.culvert was developed few years back (GRASS GIS 7.8.2) and does not exist in 8.3.1 https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass83/addons/grass-8.3.1/.

I also checked 7.8.2 from https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass-7.8.2/ and r.stream.culvert still does not exist. What can I do in this case?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are a *problem-solving* site, not a tutorial one. Broad Questions with bullet lists of questions are likely to be closed as lacking *focus*.

Comment: You still seem to be asking two questions.

Comment: The repo https://gitlab.com/invafish/r.stream.culvert is outside of the standard GRASS GIS addons repo, hence it is not provided as a Windows ZIP file for an easy installation with `g.extension`. As Anna wrote in https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#grassgis_community:gitter.im it is a Python script, so you can download the .py file manually and execute it from GRASS terminal or use "Launch script" from File menu in the GUI.

Comment: Thank you @markusN, I was able to simply run it with [file]-[luanch script].